# Products of power series

Tags: analyticity

consider the identity
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$$

Show that for each $n\ge0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=1$$

My trial : 
By cauchy product,

$$c_k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^i}{(n-k)!i!}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{k=i}^{n} \frac{(-1)^i}{(n-k)!i!}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{k=i}^{n}\binom nk\frac{k!}{n!}$$

I was stuck in here.
So, I tried to solve it by taking $c_k=\frac{f^{k}(0)}{k!}$. But I couldn't solve as well.. Could you please give me a few hint.. it will help me a lots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use induction and Newton's binomial theorem.

Details:
$n=0$ clearly satisfies the condition since $c_0=1$.
Next assume the formula holds for $n$ and write
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{c_{n+1-k}}{k!}
&=\frac{c_0}{(n+1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_{n-k}+(-1)^{n+1-k}/(n+1-k)!}{k!}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\bigg(1+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^{n+1-k}1^k\bigg)
=1+\frac{(1-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=1,
\end{split}
$$
concluding the inductive step and the proof.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your explanation. I have not tried to use induction.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $e^x$, on the right-hand side use the Cauchy product, on the left the geometric series and finally compare coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides.

Comment: Thank you. I think your explanation is quite clear and easy to understand